# UIWebView transparent not working in iOS < 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiwebview

In my xib i have a UIWebView control i need to make its background as transparent so that i made

1. Background = clearColor and
2. Unchecked Opaque checkbox

It is **working fine in iOS 5.0 & greater but in iOS < 5.0 a background white color is coming**.How to fix this?

Comment: You know what...the webView background color clearcolor is happening but ... the webSite you loading is have white color in its back......

Comment: my code also working....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    - (void)makeBodyBackgoundTransparent {
        for (UIView *subview in [webView subviews]) {
            [subview setOpaque:NO];
            [subview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        }
        [webView setOpaque:NO];
        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
}
```

setting your webview's background to clear color, also make sure that you set opaque to false.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Your code just says what the original question says just in code, not in interface builder. "Try doing what you're already doing" isn't a helpful answer. Your code might work _for you_ but it doesn't work for the questioner!

Answer (score -1):

In iOS < 5.0 you have to set the backgroundcolor directly in your html code too.

Include this into your HTML-Code of the Webview:

```
<body style="background-color: transparent;">
```

And set the background-color and the opaque value of the webview:

```
[self.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
```